# reset Function displayed data in form

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, wordpress

```
     function my_fav_quote_show_optin_form() {  

        if (!empty($_POST['my_fav_quote_email'])) {

            my_fav_quote_opt_in();
        }
            $out2 = '';

            $out = '<form action="" method="post" id="requestQuote">';
            $out .= '<table style="padding="0px" width="40px">';
            $out .= '<tr><td style="vertical-align: middle;">Message:<br></td><td><textarea placeholder=""  name="my_fav_quote_message" id="my_fav_quote_message"></textarea></td></tr>';
            $out .= '';


            $out .='<tr><td colspan="2">';
            if ( function_exists( 'my_fav_quote_display' ) ){
                $out .= my_fav_quote_display();
            }



            if ( function_exists( 'my_fav_quote_display3' ) ){
                $out .= my_fav_quote_display3();
            }


            $out .='</td></tr>';
            $out .= '<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><input type="submit" value="Request Quote" onclick="return chk_validation()" style="background-color:#000;color:#FFF;padding:5px;margin-top:10px;border:none;cursor:pointer;"/>  <input type="button" onclick="formReset()" value="Reset form" /></td></tr>';

            $out .='</table></form>';
            echo $out;
            ?>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function formReset()
    {
    document.getElementById("requestQuote").reset();
    }
    //<![CDATA[
                    function validate_email(field,alerttxt)
                    {

                      apos=field.indexOf("@");
                    // alert(apos);
                      dotpos=field.lastIndexOf(".");
                       //alert(dotpos);
                      if (apos<1||dotpos-apos<2)
                        { return false;}
                      else {return true;}

                    }
                    function chk_validation()
                    {
                        if(document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_name") && document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_name").value == '')
                        {
                            alert("Please Enter Name");
                            document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_name").focus();
                            return false;
                        }

                        if(document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_email").value == '')
                        {
                            alert("Please Enter Email");
                            document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_email").focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        //alert(validate_email(document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_email").value,"Not a valid e-mail address!");
                            if (validate_email(document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_email").value,"Please enter valid e-mail address!")==false)                        {
                            alert("Please enter valid e-mail address!");
                            document.getElementById("my_fav_quote_email").focus();
                            return false;
                            }
                        }
                        if(document.getElementById("security_code").value == '')
                        {
                            alert("Please Enter Security Code");
                            document.getElementById("security_code").focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        if(document.getElementById("quotes").value == '')
                        {
                            alert("Please add atleast one request quote");
                            document.getElementById("quotes").focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        //return true;
                    }



                    //]]>

                </script>
    <?php

    }
```

this is a  form of one of the wordpress plugin written in php i need to added a reset button for which i tried with

```
function formReset()
    {
    document.getElementById("requestQuote").reset();
    }
```

but that was not working

Wordpress Plugin Usage [link](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/quote-cart/trunk/quote-cart.php)

I want to reset the form when the user click on reset button all the data that is displayed should be removed from all the feilds and from 
from (the two functions my_fav_quote_display3 &the my_fav_quote_display & ) which was not actually happening.

In what why I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reset a form with a reset type button.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: have tried this first but this will only reset the form but i need a thing which can clear the details displayed by the two functions also

Answer (score 1):

Your reset() call successfully resets the form, which is exactly what it you wanted it to do.

The problem is that there's more than just a form to clear: You seem to be using a plugin, which provides both the `my_fav_quote_display()` functions. There is really no way to tell what these methods do, nor which, if any, fields in your database are used by this plugin, because you haven't shown any of the relevant code (nor even mentioned the plugin's name).

For the quotes to disappear permanently, you need to look at your plugin's API and find out how `my_fay_quote_display()` and `my_fav_quotes_display3()`  work, and if there is a data field you can reset, or some other way to stop them from being shown.

Comment: yes got it now the plugin i am using this plugin [link](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/quote-cart/trunk/quote-cart.php) i dont want to remove them permanently  but what i need to clear the display when the want to start again  the selection the site i am using it was[link](http://mattisonsdev.info/mattisons-catering-event-quote/)

Comment: On a side note: Pasting hundreds of irrelevant lines of code will not help you in getting correct answers - we don't need to know your form elements' names, labels and description, or how you validate email addresses, for example.  You should always try to narrow down your information to what's really important for solving your problem, otherwise you'll make a lot of people skip reading your questions.

Comment: ok will remove that stuff will surely try to give  u more relevent information

Comment: Having looked at the plugin code...  It seems that the display() methods print a list of all users that have subscribed, but only for administrators.  Clearing that list along with the form would mean removing _all_ entries relating to the plugin from the database, as far as I can tell.  Are you sure this is what you want to do?  Are you sure you are using this plugin in the way it was intended?

Comment: no can u see this site [link](http://mattisonsdev.info/mattisons-catering-event-quote/) and click on add to quote button then u can see a display widget on the sidebar in that the list of items that are displayed with remove button but if their are 5 products and the user want to remove all the 5 then as of now they need to remove them manually  so i want to reset the chosen list  if the user want so all the prducts up to that time will be removed from the display

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="formReset()" value="Reset form" />
```

HTML have reset button, you dont need javascript for it.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset form" />
```

Comment: u are right but i have to clear 2 functions also the above code will only clear the fields

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna do it with javascript you could do something like:

```
<form name="myform"></form>
<script> document.myform.reset() </script>
```

Use the name tag instead of id and it should work, did for me at least.